# Impact of using mix brand of memory on performance

Tags: memory

I have a X58-USB3 Gigabyte main board. Previously, I had 3*4 Patriot 2000 but I needed more memory so added 3*4 Corsair 2000 sticks. (I couldn't find the same brand). To install the memory sticks, I put 3 Patriot sticks on (2,4,6) slots and 3 Corsair sticks on (1,3,5) slots. After increasing memory I think the speed of my computer decreased.

Is the ordering of the memory modules important?

Comment: Your motherboard's manual will specify the proper ordering for matched RAM pairs.  Order is important for dual/triple channel modules, as they need to be matched for the best performance.

Answer (score 0):

Usually different memory sticks doesnt affect on computer speed. However you might encountered rare issue, when something doesnt work as intend. Long time ago i had issue when 2 different sticks didnt work together, so i had to replace. So incase if you have warranty, just try to replace your memory sticks for same manyfacturer, but just different sticks.

In case if you wont/cant do that, just try to remove all 3 new sticks and insert them 1 by 1, so you can see which of them affect your speed